# Sexuality of Dog Owner

Tags: hypothesis-testing

My girlfriend told me a weird thing. She said "All of my friend who have a chihuahua dog is gay." and "I think a gay guy likes that dog."

The story about her friends seemed true, and I got bit curious. I asked her.

"How many your friends have chihuahua?"

She answered "three".

Intuitively, three samples are too less to say something. But, I couldn't get formal solution.

On the other hand, if the proportion of gay person in all population is 5%, the probability of all three chihuahua owners being gay is 5%$^3$ = 0.0125%. It seems too small a probability to happen by coincidence.

What can I statistically say from that fact that *all three chihuahua owner is a gay*?

Is this problem is relating to hypothesis testing? With such small sample, can I test a null hypothesis that *The proportion of gays for chihuahua owner is the same as one for all population*?

Comment: If the Chihuahua owners know each other, the probabilities they individually own a Chihuahua may not be independent.  My choice in pet is pretty influenced by other people's pets that I've known.

Comment: You could do a chi-squared test if you had the proportion of chihuahua owners.

Comment: *She said "All of my friend who have a chihuahua dog is gay." and "I think a gay guy likes that dog."* Show her the Bayes' Theorem and tell her that she confuses P(Gay|Like chihuahua) with P(Like chihuahua|Gay). Without knowing P(Gay) and P(Like chihuahua) her speculation is not substantiated. This is important because a lot of misconceptions are related to this: e.g A certain race, G, is the largest occupants of prisons, hence people of race G are likely to be criminals.

Comment: @MatthewDrury it may also be the opposite: it may make gay males more likely to meet other gay-Chihuahua-owners if they themselves own Chihuahua and so it may make this subpopulation clustered ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because personal coincidences are not good questions, as discussed here: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3207/121522

Comment: See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/top-k-list-of-reasons-to-close-a-question-immediately/3207#3207

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining statistical probability related to a string event of dates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296541/determining-statistical-probability-related-to-a-string-event-of-dates)

Answer (score 1):

Since those events could be dependent or you can encounter some sort of confounding variable (for example: there is a magazine/website that is often read by gay people and it influences their selection of the breed), I suppose the good alternative to classical hypothesis testing would be to Bayes factors. More on those you can read on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor.