# The odds of matching ages being the same day of the week for 2 people (father and daughter)

Tags: statistical-significance, information-theory

What are the odds that (despite having different birthdays) my daughter (born November 16, 2006) and I (Feb 8, 1979) have had each consequestive birthday on the same day of the week, we were both born on a Thursday and every birthday thereafter has been the same day of the Week. My 18th was a Saturday, her’s will be a Saturday, my 30th was a Sunday, her’s will be a Sunday too. In fact every single year, her age and the day that her birthday lands on is an exact match for the day that my birthday was when I turned the same age.
I imagine the odds of knowing somebody who coincides this way with yourself are quite high, combined with the fact that we are parent and child. I’d like to get a statistical figure of the likelihood or a ratio of how many times this can occur in any given combination of years between two people, is there a formula that suggests the number of years apart for these coincidences to possibly occur? such as every 9 years or a number of years divisible by 9 (27 in this case)

Many thanks all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining statistical probability related to a string event of dates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296541/determining-statistical-probability-related-to-a-string-event-of-dates)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, if you read the question carefully (on first reading, I did think it was a dupe). This one seems to me to have a very simple answer (see my answer) but perhaps I am the one who is misunderstanding things.

Answer (score 0):

1 in 7.

Your being related has nothing to do with it.